Is a purely abstract world possible?
This question is about the modal aspects of a purely abstract world. Can a possible world have no concrete instances of anything, only abstractions?
Specifically can such a world be seen as a possible state of affairs that could have obtained, but didn’t? (Ignoring modal realist interpretations for the time being).
Plato's "Theory of Forms" seems to imply that yes such a world is possible. However, I can't help but think that lurking behind this supposedly pristine world of the abstract we are actually injecting perfect concrete exemplars to which others are compared, as opposed to true "abstracta".
However, Aristotle would disagree (see here) [emphasis mine]:

The founder of modal logic, Aristotle, has special reason to deny that ‘Necessarily (p or q)’ entails ‘Necessarily p or necessarily q’. Aristotle believed that all abstract entities depend on concrete entities for their existence. Yet he also believed that there are necessary truths. The existence of any particular individual is contingent but it is necessary that some individuals exist.

Source: Sorensen, Roy, "Nothingness", The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy (Spring 2023 Edition), Edward N. Zalta & Uri Nodelman (eds.), URL = https://plato.stanford.edu/archives/spr2023/entries/nothingness/.
In modal logic terminology:
Let A be the set of abstracta and I(a) be a concrete instance of a ∈ A.
Necessary truth of abstracta (A) 
∀ a∈A □a; 
Platonic Axiom 
◇∀a∈A ¬∃I(a)
However, it's not clear to me how the abstracta in such a world could have any meaning without at least one concrete instance to refer to. For example, if we consider abstracta as encodings then they implicitly depend on at least one concrete instance for their semantics.
So, in what sense can a purely abstract world be said to exist apart from any concrete instances in that world?
———
A related issue here may be that it depends on if I am a concretist or abstractionist when I conceive of possible worlds; however, both views would seem to agree that when we say something is possible we mean it as a metaphysically viable state for a world to be in.

Your own source wrote "While both ordinary and abstract objects exemplify properties, only abstract objects encode properties... The comprehension principle asserts that for each expressible condition on properties, there is an abstract object that encodes exactly the properties that fulfill (satisfy) that condition. Therefore encodings doesn't mean dependence of concrete instances for their semantics, but (universal) properties which are also abstract as universals...

@DoubleKnot but what makes something an encoding?

Abstract objects excel at encodings, such as the standard numbers of PA due to the important and famous number-theoretic unique factorization theorem, Godel leveraged this for his incompleteness theorems to encode FOL along with PA axioms, schemes and sentences...

Can you please clarify what you mean by "possible"? Epistemically possible? Logically possible? Metaphysically possible? Physically possible? Scientifically possible? Can you give an example of something that you would consider to be possible? Additionally, there is consciousness (we know we exist because we are conscious), so if everything is abstract, then cosnciousness would need to be abstract, but wouldn't that be a problem?

@user80226 I’m using modal logic in the metaphysical mode (see tag). https://iep.utm.edu/mod-meta

@DoubleKnot thank you! But can such encodings be the only things that exist (metaphysically?)

It seems to me that in Zalta's formalism the existence of any ordinary object is contingent. So, a world without any ordinary objects should be possible? An abstract object need not be an "instance of an ordinary object"; it could be an instance of the abstractum "nothing" (or "thing" or "the One" or of some unspecified abstractum), and all abstracta could then be encodings of other abstracta? (In Proclus' neo-platonism the primordial form is also not Being, but the One - transcending both Being and Non-Being...)

I think of Zalta's formalism as "reification gone crazy". The unrestricted comprehension principle seems to doom the whole project from the start. If you need to allow a "round square" as an abstract object, I don't understand how this formalism can be fruitful or elucidate any actual questions.

@mudskipper +1 agree that freewheeling abstractionism seems to implode lol

The question "Why does something exist, rather than nothing?" is an old chestnut in philosophy. If you can show that it is metaphysically impossible for no concrete objects to exist, then great, you're probably the most successful philosopher ever. Anyway, in formal terms: the converse Barcan formula is a theorem in the usual framework for first-order S4 modal logic, so everything that exists necessarily exists, so an empty universe is impossible. But that's simply because you can't use that framework to reason about possible non-existence of actually-existing objects at all.

@user509184 can you put that in an answer? And show the implication you speak of ?

@mudskipper Did you read his book, "Abstract objects"? He takes great pains to explain how his formalism elucidates many often-considered questions in philosophy. Every other chapter (chapters II, IV, and VI) is entirely devoted to applications of the theory to well-known difficult questions in metaphysics.

@Annika I think I will have time for this later today, sure.

@user509184 - I didn't read the book. Only read parts of his papers and online publications. So far the only somewhat interesting paper (in my biased view) was the analysis of Anselm's argument.

@Annika Sorry, I will not have time to write that answer, but you can find the proof in, for example, Awodey--Kishida "Topology and Modality: the Topological Interpretation...," pg. 12, sentence beginning "Listing some theorems of FOS4". The argument is much older than that paper, but that's the easiest place I know to find it. If it's useful, Fitting--Mendelsohn "First-Order Modal Logic" has an excellent full treatment of the standard semantics for quantified modal logic, where these issues involving the Barcan formulas arise. (They are not issues in propositional modal logic at all.)

No, but with the disclaimer that this cannot be answered without the discussion turning into one about semantics. What do you mean by “exist”? Well, the only examples of a manifestation of abstract entities that we can all agree on occurs in our minds, but minds depend on brains, and brains depend on a physical world.
This is similar to the problem of disembodied minds. We can certainly imagine the concept of a mind existing without a body, similar to how we can imagine a car moving without any engine. We thus think that this is logically possible, but this is a fallacy.
Richard Carrier, in a slightly unrelated but still related article about the supernatural, summarizes this quite well,

We can observe a mind think, or a car roll uphill, without seeing the engine inside actually bringing about the effect (the person’s brain; the car’s motor). So we can conceive of a mind thinking without a brain, and a car rolling uphill without an engine. But that’s an error. In fact, neither is possible: minds can’t exist without brains, nor can cars roll uphill without some complicated machine bringing that about. It is our inability to see the mechanism, and our seeing instead only a cause and an effect (without all the intervening messy system of causes—the neurons and blood vessels, the gears and pistons—linking the one to the other), that leads us to imagine the supernatural: a disembodied mind; a magical car.


We don’t see the hidden mechanism; so we think we don’t need the hidden mechanism. But that’s a fallacy.


Activity without mechanism. Complexity without components. And there’s the rub.
Activity without mechanism, actually logically entails complexity without components. They are just translations of the same phrase, synonymous. But…isn’t complexity without components by definition a logical contradiction?

The same applies to abstract “worlds”. Saying that abstract worlds exist implies that they manifest somehow. But manifestation involves some level of activity without any parts, another form of complexity without components, which is a contradiction.

For this reason, the mere fact that we can imagine something, that we can conceive of it, does not mean it is logically possible. Because it might only be logically possible inside a computer system simulating it (in this case, that being our brain). We can’t “conceive” of something apart from the machinery of our brain, so we can’t ever actually test the logical possibility of something outside our brain. We can only ever test the logical possibility of simulating something in a brain. And that’s a significant limitation we cannot overlook.


+1 this is where my mind was going. Unless “exist” becomes synonymous with “not inconsistent”.

The concrete is required in order for the abstract to even be comprehended. So long as concrete is in reverence to specifics themselves. Partially this is due to the fact that the concrete allows for the abstract to even be defined. If defined, we see that the abstract typically attempts to contradict the concrete, so long as it rejects specifics. If this is the case, the abstract starts to go into a seeming paradox with the concrete. This seeming paradox is one that rejects the concrete, as in specifics. A prime example of this is the idea of method without method. Or even specifics without specifics. This does not imply that the abstract does not persist, rather the abstract attempts to contradict that which persists in a manner that is ordered, or definite. In abstract art, we see that it is typically understood as lacking method. Regardless, the method would be that which is "methodless". This is where the contradiction and even paradox thrive.
If a purely abstract "world" were to exist apart from any concrete instances within that world, we would need to understand the abstract as method-full or definite, prior to the concrete, and even existing or persisting as some sort of expression that is not necessarily physical. So long as concrete does not imply specifics that could be immaterial, prior to the physical, we see a separation of the concrete and the abstract. This is due to the fact that concreteness itself is understood as physicality, as well as definite or specific, whereas abstract can be understood as prior to physicality or concreteness. This would allow for the understanding or notion that the immaterial does not influence the material. The abstract world itself would need to be outside of the physical, but furthermore not necessarily a world, as we understand world as something that is concrete, as in physical. If the world is specific, not just physical, then we can see a merger of the concrete and the abstract.

According to religious thought the human being is body and soul, the rest of parts can be grouped in one of those great categories because in my opinion the body is the vegetal part of the human being and the soul is the animal and spiritual part. The vegetal part would be the female principle, and the animal and spiritual would be the masculine one, just like in procreation happens: the ovule and the sperm. An abstract world would be an idea in some kind of racional instrument like a piece of paper a computer or a book, and there are fourth things needed to let a reality exist: infinite (in time and space), balance between those masculine and female principles, expansion, inteligence to put an order, will of creation and love, and some kind of raw material.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
